Calendar created with NextJS does not start with correct day
I have this code that renders a calendar (screenshot either attached or in the next message). Last month we started on a monday so it was fine but this month (may), it starts on a Wednesday. So, the calendar starts rendering on a Wednesday. I want to add a couple of empty boxes at the start so it always starts on a monday.
Basically the Mon, Tue columns move to the start and the others get pushed.
I tried adding an if statement that checks if the current month starts with anything else other than Monday and if it does add some empty divs, but it just pushes it to the right (same issue, starts with a wednesday but gets pushed).
Not sure if my logic was wrong.
Current Calendar.tsx
{(calSelection === "month" && currentCal && Object.keys(currentCal).length > 0) && 
Object.keys(currentCal).map(day => (
  <div key={day} className="w-[12vw] flex flex-col items-center">
    <p className="font-semibold w-[12vw]">{day}</p>
    <div>
      {currentCal[day] && currentCal[day].length > 0 && currentCal[day].map(date => (
      <p key={date.fullDate} className="w-[12vw] h-[14vh] border-[1px] border-[#9297B0]">{date.fullDate.split("T")[0].split("-")[2]}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
))}

The screenshot attached is so you can see what I mean. I need Monday to go to the start and the other items get pushed down and then I add a couple of empty boxes until the correct day

This is the code I had created for it to push it but as I said the whole calendar gets pushed
{Array.from({ length: moment().startOf('month').day() }).map((_, index) => (
  <div key={`empty-${index}`} className="w-[12vw] h-[14vh] border-[1px] border-transparent"></div>
))}

It just pushes the whole calendar to the right and adds a couple of boxes
https://gist.github.com/imdarkk/b7e78f87fca82d8ec457e97537e515f9

Is there a reason why you are building the calendar from scratch?

@Hilory. -  No specific reason other than the customization I want to have on it. I don't like the other packages I researched and found

Can you host this on jsfiddle, codepen, or an online editor and update the question with the link?

@Hilory - I was not able to make a jsfiddle or anything similar work but I updated it with a gist

This is the solution I came up with: https://gist.github.com/imdarkk/8e5bc5f0c88200af8f3bc59d95bfb698 (Lines 17 through 37)
// Get number for first day of month
            let firstDay = moment(curr.month, 'MMMM').startOf('month').isoWeekday(); // 0 Sunday 1 Monday 6 Saturday

            // if it isn't equal to 1 (which is Monday) get in the if
            if (firstDay != 1) {
                // get the difference between the first day of the month and the monday
                let diff = firstDay - 1;
                // get the previous month name
                const previousMonthName = moment(curr.month, "MMMM").subtract(1, 'month').format('MMMM');

                // start a for loop until the difference runs out
                for(let i = 1; i < firstDay; i++) {
                    // get all the items from the previous month and the current day (i which equals to the number of the day in iso)
                    const previousMonthDays = acc[previousMonthName][moment().day(i).format('ddd')];
                    const lastItem = previousMonthDays[previousMonthDays.length - 1];

                    console.log('last item for ', curr.month, previousMonthName, moment().day(firstDay).format('ddd'), lastItem)
                    if(acc[curr.month][moment().day(i).format('ddd')].length == 0) {
                        acc[curr.month][moment().day(i).format('ddd')].push(lastItem)
                    }
                }
            }

The solution ended up being in the backend but if anyone has a solution for the frontend it is still accepted
